# Remove paragraph spacing

Tags: c#, flowdocument

I have a function to print the FlowDocument as following:

```
public static void printDocument(FlowDocument printDocument)
    {
        TextRange sourceDocument = new TextRange(printDocument.ContentStart, printDocument.ContentEnd);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        sourceDocument.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
        FlowDocument flowDocumentCopy = new FlowDocument();
        TextRange copyDocumentRange = new TextRange(flowDocumentCopy.ContentStart, flowDocumentCopy.ContentEnd);
        copyDocumentRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);

        PrintDocumentImageableArea ia = null;
        XpsDocumentWriter docWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref ia);
        if (docWriter != null && ia != null)
        {
            DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocumentCopy).DocumentPaginator;
            paginator.PageSize = new System.Windows.Size(ia.MediaSizeWidth, ia.MediaSizeHeight);
            Thickness pagePadding = flowDocumentCopy.PagePadding;
            flowDocumentCopy.PagePadding = new Thickness(
                Math.Max(ia.OriginWidth, pagePadding.Left),
                Math.Max(ia.OriginHeight, pagePadding.Top),
                Math.Max(ia.MediaSizeWidth - (ia.OriginWidth + ia.ExtentWidth), pagePadding.Right),
                Math.Max(ia.MediaSizeHeight - (ia.OriginHeight + ia.ExtentHeight), pagePadding.Bottom));
            flowDocumentCopy.ColumnWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
            docter.Write(paginator);
        }

    }
```

When I print the document, the gap of the paragraph spacing is too big .. it's kinda waste of the paper .. is there a way for me to remove the paragraph spacing, or make the space smaller?

```
<RichTextBox AcceptsTab="True" AllowDrop="True" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Lucida Console" FontSize="10" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0" Name="TxtSource" Padding="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderBrush="#FF8C8E94" >
                    <RichTextBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                            <Setter Property="Block.Margin" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </RichTextBox.Resources>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with FlowDocument to answer but when searching about it I found this, which might be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749187(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've already set the margin to 0 .. please refer to my post again, as i've just amended it by adding the RichTextBox code..